# Dripping in a Kitchen-aid refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

We have a Kitchen-aid French door refrigerator with bottom freezer.

What causes dripping onto the top shelf of a refrigerator?

Drips are occurring to the left of the water filter, but not from the water filter compartment!

Comment: What have you done to investigate? Have you tried inspecting the filter and its connections? Water will take the path of least resistance. Is there a water source above the drip?

Comment: Have you ruled out condensation?

Comment: Please add some pictures